# Cordova Android: Create and display a webview on top of the existing webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I would like to know how to create and display a webview on top of the existing webview in a Cordova Android app.

I am trying to show a loading screen when app launches.

In `MainActivity.java`, I am passing loading screen's HTML path to my custom `Loader` class's `#show` method.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Loading View ---------------------------
    String loadingHTMLPath = getLoadingHTMLPath();
    Loading loader = new Loading();
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    loader.show(loadingHTMLPath, appContext);
    //-----------------------------------------

    loadUrl(launchUrl);
  }
```

`Loader` extends `CordovaPlugin` as I need this to be a plugin. This is `Loader#show`:

```
  public void show(String loadingHTMLPath, Context context) {
    WebView loadingScreen = new WebView(context);
    loadingScreen.loadUrl(loadingHTMLPath);
    loadingScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
```

This compiles and runs without an error, but my loading screen is not displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: why dont you just show loading on existing webview?

Comment: There is a good reason to do so in this app.

Comment: take a look into the splash screen plugin, it presents a native view over the webview

Comment: @jcesarmobile thanks. I am able to display WebView now. But it does not execute any javascript in it. Any ideas? I have posted a separete question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600035/cordova-android-no-js-when-displaying-a-custom-webview-on-app-start