# Cordova Android: no js when displaying a custom webview on app start

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I would like to know why my JavaScript won't execute in the my WebView.

In my app, I am displaying a custom webview on top of the main view on app start by overriding `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`. The webview is filled with HTML and Javascript from a file.

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    // The next line creates webview with the content from my html file that contains javascript.
    WebView loadingScreen = Loading.createLoadingScreen(this, getLoadingHTMLPath(), appView);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    loadingScreen.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    loadingScreen.setMinimumHeight(display.getHeight());
    loadingScreen.setMinimumWidth(display.getWidth());

    Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    loadingDialog.setContentView(loadingScreen);
    loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
    loadingDialog.show();
```

This successfully displays my WebView, but no JavaScript in it is executed. (The HTML file contains `<script>` tag after `<body>`) I am confused because I have taken similar approach in iOS and it worked.

My inkling is that I am not able to execute JavaScript in the `onCreate` stage, but I am not sure. Any suggestions as to why this happens and possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to use `WebSettings#setJavaScriptEnabled` to enable JavaScript execution.

By default, the `setJavaScriptEnabled` is set to `false`. That was why my JavaScript was not running.

In my case, I had to add:

```
loadingScreen.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```